# Even after incrementing the value of the variable it won't change in the while loop

Tags: c

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<ctype.h>
    int main()
    {
    char s[] = "We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize";

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
    }
    int i=0;
    int n=1;
    int counter =0;
    char *s1;
    s1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
    s1[0] = s[0];

    int k=0;
    while(s[i]!='\0')
    {

            for( k=0;k<strlen(s1);++k)
            {
                if(s[i] == s1[k] && s[i] !=' ')
                ++counter;


            }
            if(counter==0 && s[i]!=' ' )
            {
                ++n;

              s1 = realloc(s1, sizeof(char) * (n));
              ++k;
              printf("%d :  %d\n",n,k);
              s1[k] = s[i];
            }


        ++i;
        counter =0;
        k=0;
    }
    s1 =realloc(s1 , sizeof(char)*(n+1));
    s1[n] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",s1);

    if(n == 26)
    printf("yes");
    else
    printf("No");

    return 0;
}
```

This program seeks to check whether the word is  pangram or not..
It takes a letter from the array s and stores it in array s1 if the letter is not repeated in the latter. Thus if the length of the array s1 after the while loop finishes is 26 it has all the letters possible.
But when i tried printing the s1 array it shows only w has its contents..
Confused to the extreme...

Comment: At least you have a problem with `strlen(s1)` since you don’t null terminate it. You have n, use it. Otherwise, have you stepped your code through with a debugger to see what is happening?

Comment: I am not sure why you are using malloc() and realloc().  Is this a requirement of a professor or instructor?  Can you do this without using malloc()?

Comment: I am required to use malloc ,calloc ,realloc actually !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `++k` (inside the `if` statement) is not needed, remove it and it will work:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<ctype.h>
    int main()
    {
    char s[] = "We promptly judged antique ivory buckles for the next prize";

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
    }
    int i=0;
    int n=2;
    int counter =0;
    char *s1;
    s1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*n);
    s1[0] = s[0];
    s1[1]='\0';

    int k=0;
    while(s[i]!='\0')
    {

            for( k=0;k<strlen(s1);++k)
            {
                if(s[i] == s1[k] && s[i] !=' ')
                    ++counter;

            }

            if(counter==0 && s[i]!=' ' )
            {
                ++n;

              s1 = realloc(s1, sizeof(char) * (n));
              /* ++k; */  /* <== REMOVE IT */
              printf("%d :  %d\n",n,k);
              s1[k] = s[i];
              s1[k+1]='\0';
            }


        ++i;
        counter =0;
        k=0;
    }
    s1 =realloc(s1 , sizeof(char)*(n+1));
    s1[n] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",s1);

    if(n == 26)
    printf("yes");
    else
    printf("No");

    return 0;
}
```

`k` was already incremented at the end of the `for` statement, so the `++k` later is the cause for the wrong result. Also `s1` should be initialized as `NULL` terminated, and should be kept `NULL` terminated inside the `if` statement, as without it `s1` likely to contain garbage.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I was really stumped due to this question . And yes i should have realized this mistake :(

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. I might get used this website!